# chr() ord() entering spaces ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)

Tags: python

I am trying to create a Vigenere Cypher in python and have come across this problem (it is probably me being either blind or just stupid!) and need some assistance, the main encrypt/decrypt function works fine but I am trying to include spaces in the input message and keyword, when I try and type in "hello there" by the keyword "hello there" it gives me this output

```
    crypt += chr(new)
ValueError: chr() arg not in range (0x110000)
```

this is my code:

```
import sys #This imports the "system" module, this allows me to safely close the code
accept_yes = ["YES", "Y"]
accept_no = ["NO", "N"]
accept_encrypt = ["ENCRYPT", "E"]
accept_decrypt = ["DEDCRYPT", "D"]
accept_exit = ["EXIT"] #These lists create a group of allowed inputs
def Task2(): #This defines a function so I can call it later in the code
    encrypt_or_decrypt = input("Do you wish to Encrypt, Decrypt or Exit?  ").upper() #This asks the user to type whether they would like to Encrypt, Decrypt or Exit the code
    if encrypt_or_decrypt in accept_encrypt: #This checks if the user input is one of the words inside the "accept_encrypt" list at the top of the code
        print("You chose Encrypt") #It then confirms the choice
    elif encrypt_or_decrypt in accept_decrypt:  #This checks if the user input is one of the words inside the "accept_decrypt" list at the top of the code
        print("You chose Decrypt") #It then confirms the choice
    elif encrypt_or_decrypt == ("EXIT"): #Then checks if the input was "Exit"
        print("Closing...\n\n\n\n\n\n") #If it was, tell the user that the code is closing
        sys.exit() #This shuts down the running code safely (made possible my the "import sys" at the top)
    else: #If the input was not in any of the lists above it will do the following
        print("Invalid Input") #Let the user know what has happened
        print("Try again") #And tells them to retry
        Task2() #It then calls the "Task2" function

    plaintext = input("Please enter the message you wish to Encrypt/Decrypt: ").upper() #This asks the user to input a message of their choice to encrypt/decrypt
    if not all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in plaintext): #This part checks if the "msg" variables has any spaces in it or has any numbers/symbols
        print("Invalid input") #If it does then 
        print("Try again")
        Task2()
    if len(plaintext) == 0: #This checks if the length of the input is 0 characters and if so...
        print("Invalid input length") #Tell them what happened
        print("Key must be of length 1 or more") #Explains what the problem was
        print("Please try again") #And lets them retry
        Task2() #Then calls the "Task2" function
    keyword  = input("Enter a key to offset your code: ").upper() #This asks for a different user input for the keyword to offset the previous message by
    if not all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in keyword): #This part checks if the "msg" variables has any spaces in it or has any numbers/symbols
        print("Invalid input") #If it does then 
        print("Try again")
        Task2()
    if len(keyword) == 0: #This checks if the length of the input is 0 characters and if so...
        print ("Invalid input length") #Tell them what happened
        print("Key must be of length 1 or more") #Explains what the problem was
        print("Please try again") #And lets them retry
        Task2() #Then calls the "Task2" function

    crypt = ('') #This sets a blank variable which will be altered to be the final message
    decrypt = ('') #This sets a different blank variable which will be altered to be the final message
    for n in range(0, len(plaintext)):
        new = ord(plaintext[n]) + ord(keyword[n%len(keyword)]) - 65 #This set the variable "new" as the ascii number of the message plus the ascii number of the keyword
        if new > 90: #This checks if the "new" variable is larger than 90...
            new -= 26 #If it is, minus 26 from what it was originally
        crypt += chr(new) #This makes "crypt" the ascii letter + the "new" value
        new = ord(plaintext[n]) - ord(keyword[n%len(keyword)]) + 65 #This set the variable "new" as the ascii number of the message minus the ascii number of the keyword
        if new < 65: #If the "new" variable value is less than 65...
            new += 26 #Make "new" 26 more than it was originally
        decrypt += chr(new) #And makes "decrypt" the ascii letter + the "new" value
    if encrypt_or_decrypt in accept_encrypt: #If they wanted to encrypt...
                print ("\nEncrypted message: " + crypt + "\n") #print the final message to the user
                Restart() #Calls the "Restart" function
    elif encrypt_or_decrypt in accept_decrypt: #If they wanted to decrypt...
                print ("\nDecrypted message: " + decrypt + "\n") #print the final message to the user
                Restart() #Calls the "Restart" function

def Restart(): #This defines a function so I can call it later in the code
    restart = input("Would you like to restart?\n").upper() #This asks the user if they want to restart
    if restart in accept_yes: #If the input is in the "accept_yes" list at the top of the code...
        print ("Restarting...\n\n\n\n\n\n") #Tell the user that the code is restarting
        Task2() #Then call the "Task2" function I defined
    elif restart in accept_no: #If the input is in the "accept_no" list at the top of the code...
        print ("Closing...\n\n\n\n\n\n") #Tell the user that the code is closing
        sys.exit() #Safely shuts down the running code
    else: #If the input was none of these...
        print ("Invalid Input") #Tell the user what the problem was
        Restart() #Calls the "Restart" function again

Task2() #This calls the actual encryption/decryption function
```

I would really appreaciate it if someone could help me with the problem I am facing!

Comment: A space is ASCII decimal 32. If `ord(keyword[n%len(keyword)])` is also a space you get 32 + 32 = 64. 64 - 65 makes -1, and that's outside the range of 0 through to sys.maxunicode.

Comment: any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Most implementations just skip spaces.

Comment: I thought about doing that but i really want to keep spaces as they are, so if you were to encrypt "abc abc" by "a", I want it to print "bcd bcd" with the space left where it was entered, any way of doing that?

Comment: Then just add the space to the cipher, instead of encrypting it. Do note that that makes breaking your code easier (word boundaries are a great key into breaking a Vignére cipher).

Comment: explain? not really understanding what you mean

Comment: I updated my answel already; if `plaintext[n]` is a space, add a space to your encrypted text.

Answer (score 3):

If both the plain text character and the keyword are spaces (ASCII 32) you end up with negative 1:

```
>>> plain = keyword = ' '  # space is ASCII 32
>>> ord(plain) + ord(keyword) - 65  # 32 + 32 - 65
-1
>>> chr(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(0x110000)
```

You'll have to consider how to handle this case in your cipher, or strip spaces altogether, which is what traditionally was done.

If you wanted to include the spaces, just add them to the ciphertext and continue (at the risk of making it easier to crack your code):

```
for n in range(0, len(plaintext)):
    if plaintext[n] == ' ':
        crypt += ' '
        decrypt += ' '
        continue
    # your original loop body
```

Another option is to disallow spaces in the key; you'll get encrypted text where spaces in the plaintext are encrypted to a space, the symbols `!"#$%&\'()*+,-.` or the digits 0 through to 9. To do this simply change

```
if not all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in keyword):
```

to

```
if not keyword.isalpha():
```

Comment: (Just saying but the "continue" thing can inly be used in for and while loops, just to let you know) This still doesn't work for some reason, it is still outputting the same error "ValueError: chr() arg not in range (0x110000)"

Comment: @ThatguyWhoisgood: I just tested your code with my small addition and it works for me; make sure you put that test in the right location. I've added a little more context for you.

Comment: @ThatguyWhoisgood: I tested with `Hello world` and `abcd`, which encrypts to `HFNOO YRRMF` and can successfully be decrypted again.

Comment: reallym because when i encrypt "hello world" by "abcd" is comes as "HFNOO!YRRMF" but the space is replaced with a "!"

Comment: @ThatguyWhoisgood: That's because with the key `'abcd'` your code works; the key character matched for the space is `B`, so 66. Space, 32, plus 66 - 65 is indeed 33, the ASCII code for `!`. But your error is caused by spaces *in the key*. So if you used `hello world` as the key as well you get the space in the plain text and the space in the key matched up and you get your error.

Comment: @ThatguyWhoisgood: this then gives you another option: don't allow spaces in the key, so you never end up with space + space.

Comment: is there any way of getting both plaintext and key both having spaces?

Comment: @ThatguyWhoisgood: yes, by using my `if plaintext[n] == ' ':` test.